# AEM Workflow custom input data

Tags: aem, aem-6

I need to create a workflow in AEM that for a page (specified as payload) finds all the assets used on the page and uploads a list of them to an external service. So far I have most of the code ready, but business process requires me to use a special code for each of the pages (different for each run of the workflow), so that the list is uploaded to correct place.

That is when I have a question - *Can you somehow add more input values for an AEM workflow?* Maybe by extending the starting dialog, or adding some special step that takes user input? I need to be able to somehow specify the code when launching the workflow or during its runtime.

I have read a lot of documentation but as this is my first time using workflows, I might be missing something really obvious. I will be grateful for any piece of advice, including a link to a relevant piece of docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. You need to implement a dialog step in your workflow: https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-64/developing/extending-aem/extending-workflows/workflows-step-ref.html#dialog-participant-step

Comment: But from what I see in the article the dialog is shown on workflow creation, while my problem is the input data should be specified when user starts the workflow. 
So I believe this does not really solve my problem.

Comment: It does. When the workflow is started, the step with the dialog becomes an item in the inbox. Then the data can be added/set.

Comment: @RegyN I am sorry, the was the __Dialog Participant Step__ that I wanted to reference but ... of course, I got the wrong link. I fixed the link.

Comment: Oh, ok, this makes more sense, thank you :) I don't know how I missed that dialog step. Anyway, answer accepted

Comment: The layout, search and the information of the Adobe help could be a bit better ... and again: sorry for the confusion :)

Answer (score 0):

You could:

1. Create a custom menu entry somewhere in AEM (e.g. Page Editor, `/apps/wcm/core/content/editor/_jcr_content/content/items/content/header/items/headerbar/items/pageinfopopover/items/list/items/<my-action>`, see under libs for examples)
2. Create a client-library with the `categories="[cq.authoring.editor]"`. So it is loaded as part of the page editor (and not inside the iframe with your page)
3. Create a JS-Listener, that opens a dialog if the menu-entry was clicked (see code). You can either use plain Coral UI dialogs, or my example misused a Granite page dialog (Granite reads the data-structure in cq:dialog, and creates a Coral UI component edit-dialog out of it - while Coral is the plain JS UI-framework)
4. Create a Java-Servlet, that catches your request, and creates the workflow. You could theoretically use the AEM servlet. But I often have to write my own, because it lacks some features.

---

Here is the JS Listener:

```
/*global Granite,jQuery,document,window */
(function ($, ns, channel, window) {
    "use strict";

    var START_WORKFLOW_ACTIVATOR_SELECTOR = ".js-editor-myexample-activator";

    function onSuccess() {
        ns.ui.helpers.notify({
            heading: "Example Workflow",
            content: "successfully started",
            type: ns.ui.helpers.NOTIFICATION_TYPES.SUCCESS
        });
    }

    function onSubmitFail(event, jqXHR) {
        var errorMsg = Granite.I18n.getVar($(jqXHR.responseText).find("#Message").html());
        ns.ui.helpers.notify({
            heading: "Example Workflow",
            content: errorMsg,
            type: ns.ui.helpers.NOTIFICATION_TYPES.ERROR
        });
    }

    function onReady() {
        // add selector for special servlet to form action-url
        var $form = ns.DialogFrame.currentFloatingDialog.find("form");
        var action = $form.attr("action");
        if (action) {
            $form.attr("action", action + ".myexample-selector.html");
        }

        // register dialog-fail event, to show a relevant error message
        $(document).on("dialog-fail", onSubmitFail);

        // init your dialog here ...
    }


    function onClose() {
        $(document).off("dialog-fail", onSubmitFail);
    }

    // Listen for the tap on the 'myexample' activator
    channel.on("click", START_WORKFLOW_ACTIVATOR_SELECTOR, function () {
        var activator = $(this);
        // this is a dirty trick, to use a Granite dialog directly (point to data-structure like in cq:dialog)
        var dialogUrl = Granite.HTTP.externalize("/apps/...." + Granite.author.ContentFrame.getContentPath());

        var dlg = new ns.ui.Dialog({
            getConfig: function () {
                return {
                    src: dialogUrl,
                    loadingMode: "auto",
                    layout: "auto"
                }
            },
            getRequestData: function () {
                return {};
            },
            "onSuccess": onSuccess,
            "onReady": onReady,
            "onClose": onClose
        });

        ns.DialogFrame.openDialog(dlg);
    });

}(jQuery, Granite.author, jQuery(document), window));
```

---

And here is the servlet

```
@Component(service = Servlet.class,
        property = {
                SLING_SERVLET_RESOURCE_TYPES + "=cq:Page",
                SLING_SERVLET_SELECTORS + "=myexample-selector",
                SLING_SERVLET_METHODS + "=POST",
                SLING_SERVLET_EXTENSIONS + "=html"
        })
public class RequestExampleWorkflowServlet extends SlingAllMethodsServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(@Nonnull SlingHttpServletRequest request, @Nonnull SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        final Page page = request.getResource().adaptTo(Page.class);

        if (page != null) {
            Map<String, Object> wfMetaData = new HashMap<>();
            wfMetaData.put("workflowTitle", "Request Translation for " + page.getTitle());
            wfMetaData.put("something", "Hello World");

            try {
                WorkflowSession wfSession = request.getResourceResolver().adaptTo(WorkflowSession.class);
                if (wfSession != null) {
                    WorkflowModel wfModel = wfSession.getModel("/var/workflow/models/example-workflow");
                    WorkflowData wfData = wfSession.newWorkflowData(PayloadInfo.PAYLOAD_TYPE.JCR_PATH.name(), page.getPath());
                    wfSession.startWorkflow(wfModel, wfData, wfMetaData);
                    MyServletUtil.respondSlingStyleHtml(response, HttpServletResponse.SC_OK, "Triggered Example Workflow");
                } else {
                    throw new WorkflowException("Cannot retrieve WorkflowSession");
                }
            } catch (WorkflowException e) {
                MyServletUtil.respondSlingStyleHtml(response, HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, e.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            MyServletUtil.respondSlingStyleHtml(response, HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Internal error - cannot get page");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But everything is already provided by the product which is needed? Also, You would need to bind the data to the proper workflow instance node. Your option only allows to pass data when the workflow is started. But in many cases, you would want to add configuration data when the workflow is running, especially when the workflow was assigned to another user/group.

Comment: But it was asked for "when launching the workflow". It is common case, and it’s very inconvenient for end users, to start the workflow in a 1st step - and then go to the inbox in 2nd step, find the started workflow and enter the data in a custom workflow step. I think it is a shame, that the standard product doesn’t offer this. But in my opinion the entire workflow engine is one of the sloppy and bug-prone parts of AEM.

Comment: "... code when launching the workflow or during its runtime." Even though I understand your point and share your view on this topic, I think this is one of the cases where deviations from the product should be considered quite carefully.